# What can I change so other animations wouldn't have to wait until the first one is finished?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I am having a problem with the animations. Currently this is how my animator looks:
[image: animator window]

I am trying to make a simple and fluid movement animation with jumping and strafing, but I have a problem where the previous animation has to end before the next one can play. This leads animation which looks like it has a delay. As for jumping, the "jump" trigger will not even play until I stand completely still.

This is the code for parameter triggering:

[image: Movement / Jumping is the next one]

This is the code for triggering jumping:

[image]

Comment: on your transitions set `hasExitTime = false` ?

Comment: They're all false. Doesn't help.

Comment: in your setup it might be easier to just use [`Animator.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) and directly jump to a certain state instead of rely on triggers and parameters and your transitions

Comment: `Animator.Play` is useful only for the jumping animation. Everything else works. I fixed the delay by just playing around with transition duration. But now for example if I start running and then jump, the jumping animation does not finish and I somewhat teleport back to the running animation mid air.

Comment: might also just want to put the jump on a different layer so it has its own state machine and can then either be weighted or completely overrule the main state machine so the base layer maintains its state

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the final version without delay. Arrows pointing towards the state "idle" have a transition duration `0.08` and they have no exit time except the state "Jump". Arrows pointing to other states from the state "Idle" have a transition duration of `0.1` and they have no exit time. Of course you can play around with the values for your liking.